# Will the ajax callback always be executed after the loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I have this Javascript/JQuery code:

```
$.ajax({...}).done(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    console.log(i);
```

Let's say the ajax request completes when the loop has reached the 5th iteration, will the browser suspend the loop execution and run the callback or will it wait for the loop to finish?

To make it more clear, is an output like this possible?

0

1

2

3

4

done

5

6

7

8

9

or will the output always be:

0

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

done

More in general I was wondering if the browser always pushes the callback, when triggered, at the bottom of the execution queue.

Comment: Don't quote me, but I'm pretty sure the callback, when triggered, will be pushed to the bottom of the call stack so *I think* it will always run after the loop.

Comment: It should always run after the loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop. However, you might still get a different output, depending on how `console.log` calls are processed.

Comment: I also think the loop will run until finished and then the callback, but i'm not sure.

Comment: @FelixKling Maybe I wasn't looking hard enough, but I didn't see anything in the link that supports this claim. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I was basically referring to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop#.22Run-to-completion.22 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop#Adding_messages

Comment: Testing empirically, it looks as though @FelixKling is correct.

Comment: I *do* know, for example, if you did `while(true){}`, then the callback would never run.  So knowing that, I assume the callback would *always* run after the loop.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's what I thought also... I also improved the question using the right terminology from your comment. Thanks

Comment: @emanuele please check my example. I know I might have done something wrong, buy on my pc and browser, the sample I created prints the "done" before the end of the loop.

Comment: the callback will always run after the loop because the callback is in the callback queue and will not be pulled from the callback queue until the stack is empty (which won't happen until after the loop is finished.) However, i'm not sure if that actually means the console.log will always result in that order, it may differ based on implementation of console.log.

Comment: For example, if calling console.log results in an action being placed into the callback queue, that action may be inserted into the callback queue after the ajax callback if the ajax completes before the loop is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could get both output example you describe, depending on the time the ajax request takes to complete.

EDIT: Note that this might **lock your browser** for a while, but it should not crash, and then prints something like `***** DONE! ***** 2828725`

```js
var promise = new $.Deferred(),
    i = 1, j = 0, to = 5000000;

promise.done(function() {
    document.write("***** DONE! *****\n" + i);
    i = to;
});

setTimeout(function() {
    promise.resolve();
}, 1000);

for(i = 1; i < to; ++i) {
    console.log(++j);
    //alert(++j);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure?  I thought the callback would be pushed to the bottom of the call stack, and wouldn't interrupt the loop.

Comment: @FelixKling added an empiric test

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: I changed your `alert`s to `console.log`s.  I didn't feel like constantly clicking on `alert` boxes.  Plus `alert` *does* actually stop execution, so it might be skewing the test.

Comment: @RocketHazmat but the promise must have enough time to resolve before the loop is done if you want to check different output.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: The problem is that your example will not actually work.  The `setTimeout` callback won't be ran until after the loop no matter what value you give it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68423/discussion-between-matteo-tassinari-and-rocket-hazmat).

Comment: Making a loop that goes to `100000000000` just crashes your browser.  It doesn't look like you can *interrput* the loop.  It *may* have worked with `alert`s, but that's because `alert` is built-in to the browser and I think it can actually pause execution.  @FelixKling: Posted in the comments to the question the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop#Adding_messages which explains why your example will not work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it does not crash my browser, only locks it for a while, and then prints something like `***** DONE! ***** 2828725`

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: I wonder if you've just happened to overflow the variable so the browser stopped the loop.  I don't think this *actually* works for the reason you think it does.

Comment: @RocketHazmat nope, works with just 5 millions on my firefox. I guess it could depend on the CPU speed and browser used.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: I don't know if this is really "correct" though.  Making the browser lockup is not something you should do in a real program.  I'm not trying to argue, I just still think this example is flawed, but I can't explain or figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The test I did seems to show the loop must complete first

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maccyd10/yVbYQ/6682/)**

```
time = new Date()
new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    onSuccess: function (response) {

        console.log('done ' + (new Date()-time))
    }
}).send();

for (var i = 0; i <= 65535; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 10000; j++) {
            if (i===65535 && j == 10000) 
            {
        console.log('loop complete ' + (new Date()-time))
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are right. I updated your fiddle to make the loop take more time: http://jsfiddle.net/yVbYQ/6683/